# Android Java Override Settings Button

Tags: java, android

Cheers :)

In my app, (or in any app I guess) you have this settingsbutton (The three horizontal lines). When I press this button, a virtual button appears that says "Settings"
What code can I use, or how can I manipulate this button to get open another activity? (Like Settings)
Thank you :)

Comment: Trivial questions like this aren't received well here since you should  be doing at least a little research before posting. Reading through the [Android  Getting started documents](http://developer.android.com/about/start.html) you would have found your answer.

Comment: -1 for low quality question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override `onOptionsItemSelected()` ex:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_settings:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,MyNewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

`R.id.menu_settings` is the id from the menu xml for your activity, ex:

activity_main.xml in \res\menu folder

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
        android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="500"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: Thank you Matt, that worked out well for me! I'm going to upvote your post as soon as possible!